# What is the meaning of the following code?

Tags: keyboard, c-preprocessor

What is the meaning of following code :

```
//Keyboard map
#define LEFT_ARROW      'P'
#define RIGHT_ARROW     'Q'
#define UP_ARROW        'K'
#define DOWN_ARROW      'L'
#define CANCEL          'F'
#define HOME            'A'
#define BLANK           'B'
#define SIGN_TOGGLE     'G'
#define KB_DECIMAL      'R'
#define KB_ZERO         'S'
#define KB_ONE          'C'
#define KB_TWO          'D'
#define KB_THREE        'E'
#define KB_FOUR         'H'
#define KB_FIVE         'I'
#define KB_SIX          'J'
#define KB_SEVEN        'M'
#define KB_EIGHT        'N'
#define KB_NINE         'O'
#define ENTER           'T'
```

Could anybody explain how it works  and why they defined in that way?

Comment: It would help if you explain where this comes from.

Comment: It looks like somebody played a prank.

Comment: @Robert: Actually, this could be legit. If this is a list of keycodes, their value has no effect on the character output

Comment: it gives funny names to capital latin letters.

Comment: Hmm, what is the key named `SIGN_TOGGLE`? Where I can find one?

Comment: there is just a tiny bit of context missing here.

Answer (score 4):

Those are just constants.  It means that the preprocessor will go through the source code and replace any instance of the word following `#define` with the character on the right, before compiling the source code.  So if there was a line like this in the code:

```
char myChar = LEFT_ARROW;
```

the preprocesor will change that code into:

```
char myChar = 'P';
```

before compiling.

Answer (score 4):

`#define TOKEN REPLACEMENT` is a [preprocessor directive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), it replaces all occurrences of `TOKEN` into `REPLACEMENT`, syntactically.

The purpose of your code snippet is to assign names to keyboard bindings, that means, if you say `if (key == KB_NINE)`, the compiler will see `if (key == 'O')`.

The advantage of using preprocessors correctly is not only readability: it also increases maintainability, in case the constants change.

The key definitions seems to be nonsense: for example, `KB_ONE` is `'C'`, however, this problem can be solved in a few keystrokes by modifying the constant in one place.

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Macro_definition_and_expansion

Answer (score 2):

These are the kind of keys you'd find on the right-hand side of a keyboard.  There is no standard way in the C runtime to let a program recognize these keystrokes.  So there have been all kinds of non-standard extensions to fix this problem.

One scheme is to let getch() return 0 when such an extended key is pressed, the next getch() call then returns a key code for that extended key.  That key code could be the original keyboard scan code.  Anything is possible, you'd have to know the original keyboard vendor and CRT supplier to have a clue.  Clearly it is ancient, proprietary keyboard interfaces was an excellent vendor lock-in strategy back in the neolithic days of computing.

Comment: Those are valid code. and i know preprocessor how work.My question is why they represented like that ? Anyone knows that?

Comment: This is unanswerable until you document what specific keyboard and CRT you use.